# General solution to differential equations using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2y''-2xy'+(x^2+2)y=0$$
The solution for the first indicial root is,
$$y_1=a_0\cos x+a_1\sin x$$
and the solution for the second indicial root is,
$$y_2=a_0\frac 1x \sin x+2a_1(\frac 1x \cos x-\frac 1x)$$
can a generalized solution be formed such that,
$$y=a_0(\frac 1x \sin x+\cos x)+a_1(\sin x+\frac 2x \cos x-\frac 2x)=y_1+y_2$$
where $a_0$ in $y_2$ is equal to $a_0$ in $y_1$ & $a_1$ in $y_2$ is equal to $a_1$ in $y_1$?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's all wrong.  The indicial equation is $r^2 - 3 r + 2 = 0$, so the indicial roots are $1$ and $2$.  The solution corresponding to the indicial root $2$, i.e. the solution of the differential equation of the form $x \left(2 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j x^{j}\right)$, is  $x \sin(x)$.  Since $2 - 1$ is an integer, the solutions for the indicial root $1$ might have needed logarithmic terms, but in this case they don't.  A solution for the indicial root $1$ is
$x \cos(x)$.

Comment: Can you recommend some resources for the Frobenius method, the text I am using skims over it.

Comment: Boyce and DiPrima has a fairly thorough treatment.  You might also try Redheffer.